# Validation and Drop Down in python

Tags: python, validation, xlsxwriter, dropdownbox

I'm attempting to teach myself python skills and took an awesome tutorial from Giraffe Academy and using some of the skills.

I created a file called country.xlsx and installed xlsxwriter to read, validate and create a dropdown box using this tutorial - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_data_validate.html

When I run or debug the code below,

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook("Countries.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

workbook = worksheet.set_column("A:A")
workbook = worksheet.set_column("B:B")
workbook = worksheet.set_column("C:C")
workbook = worksheet.set_column("D:D")
workbook - worksheet.set.row(0, 6)

heading1 = "Continent"
heading2 = "Country"
heading3 = "Capital"
heading4 = "Airline"

workbook = worksheet("A1", {heading1})
workbook = worksheet("B1", {heading2})
workbook = worksheet("C1", {heading3})
workbook = worksheet("D1", {heading4})

txt = "Select from the Dropdown List"
workbook = worksheet.data_validation("B15", {"validate": "list", "source" : "=$A$1:$D$7"})

workbook.close()
```

I receive this error

workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook('Countries.xlsx')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Can someone point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html) it seems like you have to use `Workbook` with a capital W:

`workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Countries.xlsx')`